# How can I do inline type checking without storage in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I have some interface

```
ITestInterface {
  foo: string;
}
```

I'd like to pass an instance of this interface as an argument to a function.  The function will take any object type, so it does not type check on it's own.  In order to make sure an object is of the correct type, I can use storage:

```
const passMe: ITestInterface = { foo: "bar" };
someFunction(passMe);
```

But I'd like to have a way to create the argument inline, while still doing type checking.

```
// made up example syntax
someFunction({ foo: "bar" } istype ITestInterface);
```

Is there a nice way to something like the example above inline?

I've tried using as, but it doesn't limit the type.  For example, the following is valid.

```
someFunction({ foo: "bar", hello: true } as ITestInterface);
```

Another thing I can do in this instance is modify `someFunction` to have templating, but it's not what I'd consider a great solution.  I won't always have this privilege.

```
someFunction<TYPE>(arg: TYPE) {
  // modify function definition
}

someFunction<ITestInterface>({foo: "bar"});
```

Comment: Would `someFunction(isType<ITestInterface>({foo: "bar"}))` work for you?  Or does that defeat the purpose because it's calling a function?

Comment: isType does not seem to exist by default.  So I'd be creating it right?  If that's the case, seems like a costly abstraction.

Comment: Yeah you'd have to create it.  I'm not sure how to quantify how costly it is; I imagine that's subjective

Comment: Note that `{ foo: "bar", hello: true }` is a valid `ITestInterface`, it just has an extra property.  In some cases TypeScript performs [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to prevent you from making mistakes, but it is very easy to circumvent that, especially since excess properties are allowed.  For example, `interface X extends ITestInterface {hello: boolean}; const x: X = {foo: "bar", hello: true}; const y: ITestInterface = x;`.  That's not an error, so I'm not sure exactly how to answer this now

Comment: `const t: ITestInterface = {foo: "bar", hello: true}` is an error.  Trying to get this functionality without storage (const =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific feature you're looking for, something like "type annotations for arbitrary expressions", doesn't exist in TypeScript. There is an open [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) for it currently marked as "needs proposal", so you might want to give it a  or describe your ideas if they are compelling and different from what's already in there.  But it doesn't look to me like anyone's working on it, so I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

---

There are several ways to go here, each with their own issues.

As you've seen, the easiest thing to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  This works to prevent you from passing in a *completely unrelated* type:

```
// assertion
someFunction({ foo: "bar" } as ITestInterface); // okay as expected
someFunction({ unrelatedThing: 1 } as ITestInterface); // error as expected
```

It also allows extra properties (which is still sound and type safe, an object of type `ITestInterface` isn't guaranteed *not* to have other properties... it might surprise you because you expect [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), but those only happen sometime):

```
someFunction({ foo: "bar", hello: true } as ITestInterface); // okay by design,
// excess properties are allowed
```

But the big dealbreaker here is that type assertions let you unsafely narrow types, so the following will not be an error:

```
someFunction({} as ITestInterface); // no error ?! assertions also NARROW types
```

---

The other way you could go would be to create a helper function called `isType` like this:

```
// helper function
const isType = <T>(x: T) => x;
```

This behaves almost exactly as you'd like:

```
someFunction(isType<ITestInterface>({ foo: "bar" })); // okay as expected
someFunction(isType<ITestInterface>({ unrelatedThing: 1 })); // error as expected

someFunction(isType<ITestInterface>({ foo: "bar", hello: true })); // error as you want
someFunction(isType<ITestInterface>({})); // error as everyone wants
```

But, as you said, it might not be worth it to you.  Most runtime engines will happily inline functions like `x => x` so I wouldn't think it's a *performance* issue.  But it might be an elegance issue, which is up to you.

---

Anyway, those are the best I can do.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-11RngpAh5CzBZLUZrDbIbYcaOsVrojnnS4DRPk5N672m9MBg4uXNhl4VD5fEm-f6AitV9mc3pdKg8ZCaODgJvU6Jpv3tpmdorllmnWvxgBu0EnIBQs-A6qAA)

Comment: Now that `satisfies` is a thing, how would that help with this situation?  Or would it? (I've read the GH threads and the 4.9 release notes but not quite grokking it... is `satisfies` basically a stricter `as`?  `satisfies` is otherwise undocumented.)

Answer (score 1):

First off, interfaces are supposed to be implemented by a class. Neither interfaces nor classes shall be used for type-checking simple objects in TypeScript - simply use types instead. Also, the `I` before the interface name stands for interface, so you should write `ITest` instead of `ITestInterface`:

```
// replace this:
ITestInterface { foo: string }
// by this:
type Test = { foo: string }
```

Now let's put these software-development level remarks aside and attack the core of the issue:

If you want to make sure that `someFunction` always calls objects of type `Type`, writing the function definition as the following is sufficient because TypeScript will detect anywhere in you code where it's called with something else:

```
// like this
const someFunction: (arg: Type) => any = (arg) => { /*...*/ }
// or like this
function someFunction(arg: Type): any { /*...*/ }
```

If you have some argument that you *know* is of type `Type` but somehow the TS compiler doesn't infer that, that's where you use the `as` keyword.

```
someFunction({foo: 10}); // error
someFunction({foo: 'bar'});
someFunction({foo: Math.random()<1 ? 'bar' : 10}); // error
someFunction({foo: Math.random()<1 ? 'bar' : 10} as Type);
```

And that's basically all you need to do to make your program type-safe at compile-time. Check out the code above on the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BmB7dAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gL4BQqAriQMbBHol7oC2EAYvUyyQAUAQwJkccSAEocwkiBRQA9ACoAdBpVKo1Krk48+zVoLSYcARgAMFKQG49B3o2NCz2KAHIARqM+2HfS5nfhN3HABZYWAACzUCOQATTkEpAB4LKAB+L18CTyhLG3tHYKMBUwwPKNj4pJT0zJyfP0KoawooYVxYeHsgA).

---

If, for whatever reason, you want to add an extra layer of reliability and make sure that your program is type-safe at runtime, you'll have to type check at runtime. That can induce a performance overhead, but if you just want to make sure that a few properties are on an object, that can only occupy one line in the function definition:

```
const someSafeFunction(arg: Type): any {
  if (Object.keys(arg).sort().join(',')!='propertyName1,propertyName2') throw new Error('Invalid argument type');
  /* ... */
}
```