# How do I use declare the type of an inline function in typescript with a named type

Tags: typescript

I have a thirdparty library (express) that I pass callbacks to. I have a named type `MyCallbackType` I want to declare inline callbacks as this type. I've found a way to do this, but it seems like a hack. 
So please tell me if there is a better way. This is what I do now:

```js
type MyCallbackType = (req: ...) => ...;

app.use((async (req, res, next) => {
// do stuff
}) as MyCallbackType);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do inline type checking without storage in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994206/how-can-i-do-inline-type-checking-without-storage-in-typescript)

Comment: Are you using the `@types/express` package? If the only middleware you're planning to use is your own then maybe just specify the `use` as `use(callback: MyCallbackType)` or something similar.

Comment: @dezfowler I am using `@types/express: '^14.7.0'` but there seems to be a problem with the typings. I get a `error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'` pointing to calling `next()`. I'm aware I could do the typing like that, but I'd prefer to declare it inline (hence the question).

Comment: You'd get that error if `MyCallbackType` specified `next` as optional. It would want you to have a null/undefined check before the invoke. Another way of defining your function would be `<MyCallbackType>(async (req, res, next) => { ... })` which works the same way as the `as` but it's up front so is more obvious. Disadvantage is that you can't use that in tsx files as it thinks you're trying to declare an element.

Comment: @dezfowler `<MyCallbackType>(...)` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Feel free to write an answer if you'd like and I can accept it.

`next` is incorrectly specified as optional in the express typings, which  is why I get the `error TS2722`, and basically why I'm doing this.

Comment: Looks like that optional `next` in the typings was fixed three years ago in [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/11288). Can you update the version of the type defs you're using?

Comment: Ahhh there was a rouge `"express-serve-static-core": "^0.1.1"` in my package.json. Thank you!